# syntaxerror while pasing json

Tags: python, json, syntax-error

I want to make json from text file, and make list value of `['ids']`

```
{"previous_cursor": 0, "previous_cursor_str": "0", "next_cursor": 1351473067174597097, "ids": [250718906, 66612533], "next_cursor_str": "1351473067174597097"} {"previous_cursor": -1351352880715992572, "previous_cursor_str": "-1351352880715992572", "next_cursor": 0, "ids": [113030689, 22020972], "next_cursor_str": "0"}
```

**My code**

```
import json

f = open('22580877','r')
data = f.read()
datalist = data.split('\n')
idslist = []

for i in datalist:
    datadic = eval(i)
    print(datadic['ids'])
    idslist.extend(datadic['ids'])
    datadic = {}

for j in idslist:
    print(j)

f.close()
```

the error msg is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    datadic = eval(i)
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I can't find my syntaxerror in my code. help me please!

Comment: Why are you using `eval` to parse JSON? Why not the actual `json` library? And why are you splitting on newlines rather than passing the whole thing to `json.loads`?

Comment: using eval and exec is bad practice, you should try to avoid it

Comment: The SyntaxError isn't in your code, it's in the string from `datalist` that you passed to `eval`. But as Daniel said, you should _not_ be using `eval` for this. Use the `json` module functions. `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: can you give us a sample of the file?

Comment: {"previous_cursor": 0, "previous_cursor_str": "0", "next_cursor": 1351473067174597097, "ids": [250718906, 66612533], "next_cursor_str": "1351473067174597097"}

{"previous_cursor": -1351352880715992572, "previous_cursor_str": "-1351352880715992572", "next_cursor": 0, "ids": [113030689, 22020972], "next_cursor_str": "0"}

Comment: it is my sample file (thanks for help!) (each dictionary line separate by 'enter')

Comment: I solve my problem with using json.loads ! thanks for help!

Comment: Please write an answer showing how you solved it then mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've been handed a file with a jsonified string on each line of the file. From your error message I kinda wonder if your file is corrupt or not formatted the way you think it is. However, if I had been given the task you've supplied I'd do something like this...

```
import json, traceback
idslist = []
with open('22580877', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    datalist = data.split('\n')
    for idx, json_string in enumerate(datalist):
    try:
        json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
        idslist.extend(json_obj['ids'])
    except:
        print "bad json on line {} with traceback:\n{}".format(idx+1, traceback.format_exc())

for id in idslist:
    print(id)
```